# Bind "IsEnabled" to ListView in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

Ok, I've got a `ListView`. I've set `ItemsSource` from code. This `ListView` has Property `SelectionMode="Multiple"`. But I'd like to disable some items from selecting.

```
XAML: //not working
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" SelectionMode="Multiple">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=enabled, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <!-- my template -->
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Although, I cannot set each ListViewItem from code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Converter? See [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/) easy tutorial.

Comment: No reason to use Converter, because I have to bind, right? `{Binding Path=data, Converter={Static Resource}}`. But I cannot set binding in `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: @VladislavKasianenko What are you showing in that ListView? A CheckBox with text?